# Dynamic Programming - Fibonacci

Tags: python, dynamic, fibonacci

So basically, I am a learning programmer and this week I was introduced to dynamic programming. Our task was to find the Fibonacci sequence using dynamic programming. This pseudo code was supplied which would obviously be in a function:

```
init table to 0s
if n ≤ 1
   return n
else
   if table[n-1] = 0
      table[n-1] = dpFib(n-1)
   if table[n-2] = 0
      table[n-2] = dpFib(n-2)
   table[n] = table[n-1] + table[n-2]
return table[n]
```

The majority of this was simple to change to code but I'm not sure how to initialise the table of 0s. I know it should be a list but I'm not sure if it should be inside the function or outside or how many zeros I should initialise it with. This is what I wrote, nothing complicated:

```
def dynamicFibo(n):
   # initialise table of 0s
   #base case
   if n <= 1:
       return n
   #recursive case
   else:
       if table[n-1] ==  0:
           table[n-1] = dynamicFibo(n-1)

       if table[n-2] ==  0:
           table[n-2] = dynamicFibo(n-2)

       table[n] = table[n-2] + table[n-2]
   return table[n]
```

I would be thankful if someone could show me the way to go with this. Also, in general I struggle to understand the basis of dynamic programming so if there are any good resources you could suggest I would be delighted, or even if you could give a good explanation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can initialize your `table` with:

```
table = [0 for _ in range(n+1)]
```

since you want to have at least `n+1` items in your table to allow to access `table[n]` (remember that lists are zero-indexed so the `nth` item is accessed with `(n-1)`)

However, you would want to ensure that you are not creating new lists every time since that would defeat the purpose of dynamic programming. So you can have `table` as what I call an "invisible" parameter, ie a parameter with a default parameter that is used at every recursive call. Your function would then look like this:

```
>>> def dynamicFibo(n,table = []):
   while len(table) < n+1: table.append(0) #this does the same thing except it doesn't change the reference to `table`
   #base case
   if n <= 1:
       return n
   #recursive case
   else:
       if table[n-1] ==  0:
           table[n-1] = dynamicFibo(n-1)

       if table[n-2] ==  0:
           table[n-2] = dynamicFibo(n-2)

       table[n] = table[n-2] + table[n-1]
   return table[n]
>>> dynamicFibo(12)
144
>>> dynamicFibo(300)
222232244629420445529739893461909967206666939096499764990979600
```

[reference](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html)

as you can see, I used a while loop instead of a list comprehension. This is essentially the same thing except we cannot be changing the reference of `table` or else the recursive calls will create a new table each time unless you pass it in as a paramater. This also allows the table to expand as necessary if you call `dynamicFibo` more than once with increasing numbers, but maintain all the old numbers. This is clearly seen by adding a `print(table)` line in the function:

```
>>> dynamicFibo(12)
[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144]
144
>>> dynamicFibo(14)
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377]
377
```

I added the `print(table)` right before `return table[n]`

Comment: How old `table` is get referencing when we called `dynamicFibo(14)`? Can you please explain?

Answer (score 3):

## There is a simple solution that worked for every one...

```
def fib(n):
    table = []
    table.append(0)
    table.append(1)
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        table.append(table[i-1] + table[i-2])
    return(table[n])
```

Comment: `fib(50); fib(51)` recalculates everything.